# G in less doesn't go to the bottom

Tags: linux, less

when I use `G` in `less` it's only scrolling down one screen length, rather than going to the bottom. `vim` on the otherhand will scroll to the bottom.

Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct behaviour for less - from the man page :
*" G or > or ESC-> Go to line N in the file, default the end of the  file.   (Warning:  this  may  be slow if N is large, or if N is not specified             and standard input, rather than a file, is being read.)
"*

However if you are using "ESC G" it goes to the last line which is currently buffered - maybe this is what you are doing?